# Microsoft Edge Delete History and Cookies Programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, cookies, vbscript, microsoft-edge

Is there any way to delete history & cookies of Microsoft Edge browser using VBScript or .net?

Like Internet Explorer, deleting the history form "%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History" folder or Rundll32 commands?

**Rundll32 commands**

*Delete Cookies:* 
rundll32.exe,InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

*Delete History:* 
rundll32.exe,InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

**Edit:**

Found an solution for clearing cookie http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/cookies.htm. Deleting files from following 4 folders will clear cookies without affecting history and cache.

`1. \Users\user name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3‌​d8bbwe\AC\#!001\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies`

`2. \Users\user name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3‌​d8bbwe\AC\#!002\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies`

`3. \Users\user name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3‌​d8bbwe\AC\#!121\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies`

`4. \Users\user name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3‌​d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies`

**Still need help to clear history without affecting cookie and cache**

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. But the latest msedge doesn't seem to use these folders anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Safe But First You need To Close Microsoft Edge browser, Then you should delete All Sub_Folders and Files are in :

"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"

Change [username] with your own Windows Username.

VB Script Code :

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe")

for each f in folder.Files
   On Error Resume Next
   name = f.name
   f.Delete True
   If Err Then
     WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & Name & " - " & Err.Description
   Else
     WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & Name
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
Next

For Each f In folder.SubFolders
   On Error Resume Next
   name = f.name
   f.Delete True
   If Err Then
     WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & Name & " - " & Err.Description
   Else
     WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & Name
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
Next
```

Note : Run This Source AS ADMIN

Another Way :

```
Call WshShell.Run("powershell -command Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml” -Verbose}")
```

RUN AS ADMIN TOO

Comment: Thank you DRPK, deleting the entire folder will clear History, Cookie & Cache as well. I had got stuck with my requirement History clear should only delete History and Cookie clear only delete Cookie :-(.